# Entity Framework AsNoTracking breaks call to Distinct

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to load a list of distinct colors from previously loaded list of products on a page.  So to pull in the products I do this:

```
var products = Products
    .Include(p => p.ProductColor)
    .ToList();
```

Then I do some processing on the products them I want to get a list of all of the distinct colors used by the products, so I do this:

```
var colors = products   
    .Select(p => p.ProductColor)
    .Distinct();
```

And this works great, however if I add a call to `.AsNoTracking()` to the original products call, I now get an entry in my color list for each entry in the product list.

Why is there a difference in these two?  Is there a way to keep Entity Framework from tracking the objects (they're being used for read only) and to get the desired behavior?

Here is my query after adding the call to `AsNoTracking()`

```
var products = Products
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(p => p.ProductColor)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: From what you have posted .AsNoTracking should work just fine, where exactly are you putting it in your query

Comment: @LukeMcGregor, I've updated the question with my query with `.AsNoTracking`

Comment: Is it just a typo that the query ends with ToList and there is no Distinct in it?

Comment: @WiktorZychla, no, I'm wanting to get a list of all of the colors associated with the products in the list, so the Distinct call happens in the second code block.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`AsNoTracking` "breaks" `Distinct` because `AsNoTracking` "breaks" identity mapping. Since entities loaded with `AsNoTracking()` won't get attached to the context cache EF materializes new entities for every row returned from the query whereas when tracking is enabled it would check if an entity with the same key value does already exist in the context and if yes, it wouldn't create a new object and just use the attached object instance instead.

For example, if you have 2 products and both are Green:

- Without `AsNoTracking()` your query will materialize 3 objects: 2 `Product` objects and 1 `ProductColor` object (Green). Product 1 has a reference to Green (in `ProductColor` property) and Product 2 has a reference *to the same object instance* Green, i.e.

  ```
  object.ReferenceEquals(product1.ProductColor, product2.ProductColor) == true
  ```
- With `AsNoTracking()` your query will materialize 4 objects: 2 product objects and 2 color objects (both represent Green and have the same key value). Product 1 has a reference to Green (in `ProductColor` property) and Product 2 has a reference to Green but this is *another object instance*, i.e.

  ```
  object.ReferenceEquals(product1.ProductColor, product2.ProductColor) == false
  ```

Now, if you call `Distinct()` on a collection in memory (LINQ-to-Objects) the default comparison for `Distinct()` without parameter is comparing object reference identities. So, in case 1 you get only 1 Green object, but in case 2 you'll get 2 Green objects.

To get the desired result after you have run the query with `AsNoTracking()` you need a comparison by the entity key. You can either use the second overload of `Distinct` which takes an `IEqualityComparer` as parameter. An example for its implementation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) and you would use the key property of `ProductColor` to compare two objects.

Or - which seems easier to me than the tedious `IEqualityComparer` implementation - you rewrite the `Distinct()` using a `GroupBy` (with the `ProductColor` key property as the grouping key):

```
var colors = products   
    .Select(p => p.ProductColor)
    .GroupBy(pc => pc.ProductColorId)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

The `First()` basically means that you are throwing all duplicates away and just keep the first object instance per key value.