# Outof Memory Exception - Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using LINQ to select bulk data(156000 Records) from DB. But am getting the following error.

```
An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Am using select query as follows,

```
var allCompanies = from s in db.Data.AsNoTracking().ToList()
                           select s;
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: By `ToList()`, you are trying to materialize the whole table in memory. Try selecting just the fields you need, or better still, filter the data before materializing it.

Comment: Hi stuart, thanks for your response. But if i removed .ToList() then also am getting same error

Comment: As an aside, `AsNoTracking()` will [load deep copies of duplicate rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097736/entity-framework-asnotracking-breaks-call-to-distinct), not sure if this is relevant to your query?

Comment: Why would you need all those records at once? You can use pagination or process it on the server.

Comment: @StuartLC : thanks a lot, i retrived only selected fields. Its working for me

Answer (score 2):

That is a large amount of records being retrieved. You may need more memory. Have you checked the amount of memory available on your System while this program is executing?

You may want to filter the data or make use of pagination by retrieving certain fixed rows of data at a time.

If it is viable, if you are considering processing the data after retrieving it, you might as well do that in a Stored Procedure.