# C# Linq efficient way to group by without repetition of key value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

So I have the following data:

```
orders: 
[
    {id: 1, hubId: 1, number:1, IsTrue: true},
    {id: 2, hubId: 1, number:2, IsTrue: true},
    {id: 3, hubId: 1, number:3, IsTrue: false},
    {id: 4, hubId: 2, number:4, IsTrue: true},
    {id: 5, hubId: 2, number:5, IsTrue: true},
    {id: 6, hubId: 2, number:6, IsTrue: false}
]
```

I need to create a Linq query that groups the orders according to the hub Id and outputs the result in the following format

```
result: 
[
    {
        hubId: 1, 
        orders: 
            [
                {id: 1, number: 1},
                {id: 2, number: 2},
            ]
    },
    {
        hubId: 2, 
        orders: 
            [
                {id: 4, number: 4},
                {id: 5, number: 5},
            ]
    }
]
```

How do I write the linq query to acheive the wanted result?

My initial query which is not yeilding the result format I require

```
var orders = _ordersRepo.GetQueryable<Order>().AsNoTracking()
    .Where(o => o.IsTrue)
    .Select(o => new  
    {
        hubId = o.hubId,
        number = o.number,
        id = o.id
    }).ToList()
    .GroupBy(o => o.hubId)

return orders;
```

Comment: You're using EF - exactly what version of EF and .NET are you using?

Comment: Why are you using `AsNoTracking()`?

Comment: ...why are you using the Generic Repository Anti-Pattern?

Comment: The`.ToList()` is in the wrong place: `ToList()` should be at the end to materialize the query.

Comment: @Dai Latest version and AsNoTracking() is insignificant to the question. It is just a method for speed maintenance and omitting it makes no real difference to the case I am asking about

Comment: It is not "insignificant": you generally should not use `AsNoTracking()` because it breaks all kinds of features in Linq-to-Entities, like `Distinct()` and `GroupBy` which you're using: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097736/entity-framework-asnotracking-breaks-call-to-distinct https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16745

Answer (score 1):

Do it the other way around - first `GroupBy`, then select the orders from each group:

```
var orders = _ordersRepo.GetQueryable<Order>().AsNoTracking()
  .Where(o => o.IsTrue)
  .GroupBy(o => o.hubId)
  .Select(group => new
    {
      hubId = group.Key,
      orders = group.Select(o => new { id = o.Id, number = o.Number }).ToList();
    })
  .ToList();
```

You can also use the `GroupBy` overload which produces the resulting object right away:

```
var orders = _ordersRepo.GetQueryable<Order>().AsNoTracking()
  .Where(o => o.IsTrue)
  .GroupBy(
    o => o.hubId,
    (hubId, orders) => new
    {
      hubId = hubId,
      orders = orders.Select(o => new { id = o.Id, number = o.Number }).ToList()
    })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Because `AsNoTracking()` is being used, it means that the `GroupBy` step might cause garbage output because (I think, but am not certain) that it depends on entity reference tracking, especially if partial data is initially loaded into the `DbContext` but then a superset of already loaded data is reloaded... **UPDATE**: Apparently `AsNoTracking()` does break `GroupBy` and it's by-design: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16745#13518

Comment: What you are discussing is not what OP is about. The question was about the *format* of the data produced by the query, not about the content. If *content* is stalled for a scenario at hand, then that would be a different question.

Comment: Correct, however it's still an issue with both your code and the OP's code. If something is demonstrably incorrect or broken then it should be corrected or at least addressed even if it's _seemingly_ outside the OP's originally stated problem area.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat thank you, but I'm getting the error "Order" does not contain the definition for "Select" near orders = group.Select .....

Comment: That link is interesting, but it is covering a spurious case - when the grouping key is an object compared by reference - an entity. That is not the case in OP, but thank you for pointing this out, I wasn't aware of that.
When tracking is on, the `DbContext` is repeating the same instance when the same ID appears, and comparison by reference works fine. With no tracking, it has no clue that it has already sent an entity with the same ID to the output, and it generates a new object, causing equality by reference to fail.
Still, this code compares IDs, comparing by value.

Comment: @NourMawla The `group` should be `IEnumerable<Order>`. Are you sure that you have copied the code correctly? I have added an alternate solution which makes the sequence of orders more explicit.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat orders.Select(order => ...) orders is a List but in the lambda expression, order is a single order and not a list

Comment: @NourMawla There was a closing parenthesis missing. Maybe that was the reason. I have also added calls to `ToList()` to materialize the lists before completing the query.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat Groups are `IGrouping<TKey,TValue>` (which itself extends `IEnumerable<T>`, yes).

Comment: @Dai Do you see a problem in the query I have posted above? I cannot find a problem.