# Why did the object order change? I need to have a date first and a reason second, but sometimes it changes. C#, ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

EF query -:

```
List<Row> callDetailsList = (
                from a in _db.Calls.AsNoTracking()
                join b in _db.ContactMethods.AsNoTracking() on a.Contact_Method_ID equals b.contact_method_id into g1
                from s1 in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where a.RegardingEntity_ID == member_detail.MemberID
                select new Row
                {
                    Column = new List<Column>
                    {
                        new Column{ text = a.Create_Date.ToString() },
                        new Column { text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1.description) ? " " : s1.description.Trim() },
                    }
                }).ToList();
```

Data model -:

```
public class Column
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "text")]
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Column")]
    public List<Column> Column { get; set; }
}
```

Result -:

This is the third set. As you can see, the order has been changed. [0] is the reason, and [1] is the date.

[image: This is the third set. As you can see, the order has been changed. [0] is the reason, and [1] is the date.]

This is the first set. So you can see that [0] is the date and [1] is the reason.

[image: This is the first set. So you can see that [0] is the date and [1] is the reason.]

Comment: Why are you using `AsNoTracking()`? Using it means disabling 75% of `DbContext`'s functionality - and might be a contributor to this bug as `AsNoTracking()` prevents object-identity being used by `DbContext` to prevent duplicates, etc.

Comment: You should use an ordering clause

Comment: @Dai if you aren’t doing updates specifically, it’s not worth the overhead

Comment: @DanielA.White But it _breaks_ queries that depend on reference identity, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097736/entity-framework-asnotracking-breaks-call-to-distinct and https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16745

Comment: @DanielA.White - how would a ordering help, when OP is defining the List in the select? how would the defined list be reordered?

Comment: @RandRandom The question is asking about why the order changes, when the query doesn't specify an order.  Sounds like that's the problem.  Unless you add an `OrderBy` to the query, the database is in no way obligated to return the same data in the same order.

Comment: @Neil - that question isn’t about the order of the items itself but the Colums list of each item that is defined as `Column = new List<Column>
                    {
                        new Column{ text = a.Create_Date.ToString() },
                        new Column { text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1.description) ? " " : s1.description.Trim() },
                    }` why would EF reorder items within this colums list

Comment: @Neil - so Index 0 of the List column is defined as `new Column{ text = a.Create_Date.ToString() }` and Index 1 of the List column is defined as `new Column { text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1.description) ? " " : s1.description.Trim() }` - there is absolutely no reason for EF to destroy that definition and reorder the list WITHIN each item

Comment: @RandRandom Do I need to add a Priority Queue or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, don't know what your problem might be. Just wanted to point out that DanielA.White and Neil are - maybe - jumping to conclusions, you have an issue with ordering so orderby is missing easy... and they failed to understand that the broken "ordering" is with a FIXED defined list where the lists index 0 and 1 are FIXED defined IMHO there should be no reason for EF to just ignore that definition - but lets just assume that is the case than I would do this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cxgxvm